# Performance of choice vs randint

Tags: python, performance, random

I want to pick a random integer between `a` and `b`, inclusive.

I know 3 ways of doing it. However, their performance seems very counter-intuitive:

```
import timeit

t1 = timeit.timeit("n=random.randint(0, 2)", setup="import random", number=100000)
t2 = timeit.timeit("n=random.choice([0, 1, 2])", setup="import random", number=100000)
t3 = timeit.timeit("n=random.choice(ar)", setup="import random; ar = [0, 1, 2]", number=100000)

[print(t) for t in [t1, t2, t3]]
```

On my machine, this gives:

```
0.29744589625620965
0.19716156798482648
0.17500512311108346
```

Using an [online interpreter](http://repl.it/languages/Python3), this gives:

```
0.23830216699570883
0.16536146598809864
0.15081614299560897
```

Note how the most direct version (#1) that uses the dedicated function for doing what I'm doing is *50% worse* that the strangest version (#3) which pre-defines an array and then chooses randomly from it.

What's going on?

Comment: Try comparing t1, t2, and t3 with `choice(range(3))` and the answer should be clear.

Comment: `t2` and `t3` are the same, yet in `t2` you measure the creation of the list and in `t3` you don't.

Comment: @Jens Well, `t2` is relevant if you are going to be generating a few numbers at a time, `t3` saves some time in cases where you know you will need a lot of numbers.

Comment: @Superbest: agreed. But for the sake of measuring the performance of `choice()` you actually measure the generation of the list—the `0.015` time difference. As far as your question is concerned, `t2` *and* `t3` don't add helpful or discriminating information. I would say that using `t3` only is enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just implementation details. [`randint`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/random.py#L358) delegates to [`randrange`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/random.py#L284), so it has another layer of function call overhead, and `randrange` goes through a lot of argument checking and step handling. In contrast, [`choice`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/random.py#L367) is much shorter.

Here's the code path `randint` goes through for this call, with comments and unexecuted code stripped out:

```
def randint(self, a, b):
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)

def randrange(self, start, stop=None, step=_ONE):
    try:
        istart = _index(start)
    except TypeError:
        # Not executed
    if stop is None:
        # Not executed

    try:
        istop = _index(stop)
    except TypeError:
        # Not executed
    width = istop - istart
    try:
        istep = _index(step)
    except TypeError:
        # Not executed
    if istep == 1:
        if width > 0:
            return istart + self._randbelow(width)
```

And here's the code path `choice` goes through:

```
def choice(self, seq):
    if not len(seq):
        # Not executed
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
```

Comment: Note also that, for both, the difference appears to be constant.  Using `range(10000)` instead of `[0, 1, 2]` and doing `randint(0, 10000)` takes basically the same time as it does for the small example.  So basically the overhead you describe just makes `randint` 0.0000012 seconds slower per call than `choice` (assuming you can predefine your choice set).  This is not a big deal.  `t2`, however, should be avoided, since it is also timing the creation of the list, and so it will become slow with large lists.

Comment: @BrenBarn You can avoid the creation overhead if you just use a tuple.