# python random.randint vs random.choice: different outcomes usingsame values

Tags: python, random

I asked my students to write a python program in which the results of 100 rolls of a pair of 6-sided dice were stored in a list and then plotted in a histogram.

I was treating `random.choice(1,2,3,4,5,6)` as inferior to `random.randint(1,6)`, until I noticed that the histograms of the students who used `random.choice` better reflected expected outcomes. For example, the occurrence of rolls of 12 (6+6) was unnaturally high in nearly all histograms of students who used `random.randint(1,6)`. Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574605/performance-of-choice-vs-randint give this a read

Comment: What is going on is that you "noticed" chance fluctuations and ascribed to them more than is warranted.

Comment: @JohnColeman: If that were true, the kind of skewing would be random, wouldn't it? But it's not, and this is over many, many trials over multiple years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> Almost all module functions depend on the basic function random(),
>   which generates a random float uniformly in the semi-open range [0.0,
>   1.0). Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator. It produces 53-bit precision floats and has a period of 2**19937-1. The
>   underlying implementation in C is both fast and threadsafe. The
>   Mersenne Twister is one of the most extensively tested random number
>   generators in existence. However, being completely deterministic, it
>   is not suitable for all purposes, and is completely unsuitable for
>   cryptographic purposes.

So there shouldn't be any real difference in results.  However, I would disagree that `random.choice()` is inferior to `randint()`, in fact, random choice is actually faster at generating random numbers.  When you look at the source code:

```
def randint(self, a, b):
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)

def randrange(self, start, stop=None, step=1, _int=int, _maxwidth=1L<<BPF):
    istart = _int(start)
    if istart != start:
        # not executed
    if stop is None:
        # not executed

    istop = _int(stop)
    if istop != stop:
        # not executed
    width = istop - istart
    if step == 1 and width > 0:
        if width >= _maxwidth:
            # not executed
        return _int(istart + _int(self.random()*width))
```

And for `choice()`:

```
def choice(self, seq):
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]
```

You can see that `randint()` has the additional overhead of using `randrange()`

**EDIT** *As @abarnert has noted in the comments, there really is almost no performance difference here, and `randint(1,6)` is a clear and intuitive way of representing a dice roll*

I ran both for 10000 rolls, and didn't see any skewing, so there is a chance your input samples were just too small:

[image]

And here is a distribution for rolling one dice twice, it is also very uniform:

[image]

I borrowed pieces of this from these two helpful answers: [Performance of choice vs randint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574605/performance-of-choice-vs-randint)
[Is Pythons random.randint statistically random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164280/is-pythons-random-randint-statistically-random), which are helpful for further reading.

Comment: The added overhead of using `randrange` is pretty small—a function call isn't free, but compared to the work being done, it's probably not enough to make a difference. At any rate, instead of guessing, if it really matters you should test. From a quick test on my laptop, `choice(range(1, 6))` takes 1070ns, `choice((1,2,3,4,5,6))` takes 786ns, `randint(1,6)` takes 1099ns, and `randrange(1, 7)` takes 1070ns. So, it looks like that extra overhead is small enough to be lost in the noise, but `choice` is a bit faster for other reasons—as long as you have a tuple to give it.

Comment: Yea the difference in time doesn't seem to grow for larger inputs, stays fairly small.

Comment: Still, the differences are never more than 30%, and an extra 30ns to roll each die is unlikely to matter in a real problem, so a more important question is which one is clearer for a given app. I think `randint(1, 6)` is the most obvious way to implement a 1d6 roll, even if it is slightly slower than `randrange(1, 7)` or `choice` on a constant tuple.

Comment: `random.random()` is significantly faster than `random.randint()` when I did coding on `leetcode.com` because the running time is about 300-500ms.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the number of 12s you have been observing in your students' histograms is higher than the theoretical probability of rolling a 12, but not for the reason that you think.

An experiment:

```
import random

def roll_dice(method):
    if method == "choice":
        return random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6]) + random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    else:
        return random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6)

def est_prob(n,k,method):
    rolls = [roll_dice(method) for _ in range(k)]
    return rolls.count(n)/k

def test12(n,k,method):
    return sum(1 if est_prob(12,n,method) > 1/36 else 0 for _ in range(k))/k
```

Note that `test12(100,10000,"randint")` estimates the probability that a histogram of 100 dice rolls based on `randint` over-represents the sum of 12.

Typical run:

```
>>> test12(100,10000,"randint")
0.5288
```

This is greater than 50% by a statistically significant amount (10000 trials is a fairly large number of trials to estimate a probability).

So evidence of bias in `randint()`, no? Not so fast:

```
>>> test12(100,10000,"choice")
0.5342
```

With `random.choice()` you see the same thing. None of this is surprising since *most* dice roll histograms based on 100 rolls overestimate the probability of 12.

When you roll a pair of dice 100 times, the expected number of rolls which sum to 12 is 100/36 = 2.78. But -- you can only ever observe an integer number of 12s. The probability that the observed number of 12s is 3 or above (and hence leads to a histogram which over-represents 12) is P(X >= 3) where X is a binomial random variable with parameters p = 1/36 and n = 100. This probability can be worked out to be

```
P(X >= 3) = 1 - P(X<=2) 
          = 1 - P(0) - P(1) - P(2)
          = 1 - 0.0598 - 0.1708 - 0.2416
          = 0.5278
```

Thus around 53% of such histograms have "too many" 12s, something which you will see with both `random.choice()` and `random.randint()`.

It seems that you *noticed* this phenomenon more in the context of `randint`, interpreted it as bias (even though it isn't), and hypothesized that it was a deficiency in `randint`.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to generate random integers in Python is actually surprising to me:

```
import random

die = int(random.random() * 6) + 1  # The equivalent to 'die = random.randint(1, 6)
```

Just looking at it, it looks more complicated to compute but the speed difference is quite stark.

I tested both methods in a MONTY algorithm, their was around a 200% speed increase using the int(random.random) method.

Also faster than random.choice by a descent margin.