# Optimizing function for execution speed

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I am new to Python and I'm trying to optimize this code for large numbers. However I'm struggling to find an optimized way. If I run it as it is, it takes almost 4 minutes. I know it has something to do with loop and the max and randint function. I tried to use random.random as I read that is quicker but I got almost the same result. Can you think of a better way so it doesn't take that long?

```
from random import randint

def func(iters, n):
    # Function to add max random numbers to a list.
    l = [0]
    for i in range(iters):
        r = randint(0, n)
        max_l = max(l)

        if r > max_l:
            l.append(r)
        else:
            l.append(max_l + 1)

    return l

func(100000, 50)
```

Comment: Your problem stems from `max_l = max(l)` which you calculate each time round. Instead you have the information for `max_l` at the end of each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as mentioned by @quamrana the last index of the list contains the max so just access instead of calculating it every time.

```
from random import randint

def func(iters, n):

#Function to add max random numbers to a list.

    l = [0]
    for i in range(iters):
        r = randint(0, n)
        max_l = l[-1]


        if r > max_l:
            l.append(r)
        else:
            l.append(max_l + 1)

    return l

func(100000, 50)
```

Comment: On my system, this changed the runtime from ~50 seconds to <1 second.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.choice) function which is a bit [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574605/performance-of-choice-vs-randint):

```
from random import choice

def func(iters, n):
    # Function to add max random numbers to a list.

    l = [0]
    max_l = 0
    random_numbers = list(range(n))
    for _ in range(iters):
        r = choice(random_numbers)

        if r > max_l:
            l.append(r)
            max_l = r
        else:
            l.append(max_l + 1)
            max_l += 1

    return l


print(func(100000, 50))
```

And also you don't need to calculate `max` every time. The last value you insert is always the `max_l` value.