# Why does np.random.choice take so much longer than np.random.randint?

Tags: python, performance, random, numpy-random

I've been reading that np.random.choice is faster than np.random.randint ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574605/performance-of-choice-vs-randint) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243597/python-random-randint-vs-random-choice-different-outcomes-usingsame-values)), however when comparing the speed difference between

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(100000):
    np.random.choice(100)
```

and

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(100000):
    np.random.randint(100)
```

np.random.randint is appreciably faster. What's the difference between these two?

Comment: FWIW, their definitions are here: [`randint`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx#L678) and [`choice`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx#L841)

Comment: "I've been reading that np.random.choice is faster than np.random.randint" - where did you read that? Did this source provide any particular reason why one of these functions would be faster?

Comment: The prun module (or ipython magic %prun) is your friend here. Bottom line, `choice` is more _versatile_ at the cost of requiring more overhead (13 function calls) compared to randint, which only does one thing but is _optimised for that thing_ (4 function calls)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574605/performance-of-choice-vs-randint) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243597/python-random-randint-vs-random-choice-different-outcomes-usingsame-values) are a couple examples I saw. The reasoning was np.random.randint has additional overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the posts you mentioned are about the standard library [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) and you are using the 3rd-party library [numpy](https://numpy.org/). They are completely different.

In addition, numpy is not good at generating one element at a time like that. Use random (standard library), or generate them in bulk as follows.

```py
np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100000)
```

```py
np.random.choice(100, size=100000)
```

This makes the performance of both almost same.